# Web Service error when using ARR for load balancing

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, load-balancing

I have 2 web servers and 1 ARR machine for load balancing. There is an ASP.NET application running on the web servers. The system works fine except for the client side AJAX controls. The ajax controls calls web service(asmx) requests from the server. I tracked the request from the servers with Firebug both from using the ARR machine and directly from one of the web servers. Page loads successfully from web server machine. But when i use the ARR the page loads without the ajax functionality. I checked both requests with firebug. The script files for the ajax controls downloaded successufuly. But when it comes to web service calls with POST the ARR link fails. Actually there is no 404 error or something. Just no request for the POST. Any ideas?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add cache rules for not caching asmx, ashx and axd extentions. In the IIS Manager at top level click "Application Request Routing Cache". On the actions pane click "Cache control Rules". Click "Add". Apply Rule: Always, select "cache", Host name: *, URL: `*.asmx*`. Add rules for `*.ashx*` and `*.axd*`. Delete all the cached items in your cache. Restart IIS...